# Get modified teams and team channels

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to sync teams and channels between Microsoft Teams and some internal database.

I noticed that:

1. Neither **groups**, nor **teams**, nor **channels** have a concept of "last modified time". The documentation suggests to use delta queries instead.
2. It seems that among these three resources, only **groups** support delta queries. When I try to use delta queries for **teams** or **channels**, I get an error.
3. **Groups** are not considered modified if a channel is added to (or removed from) a corresponding team. Also, if a channel is renamed, the teams' **group** is not considered modified either.

So questions:

1. Is it really not supported to get modified teams and/or channels? Or am I missing something?
2. Is it planned to add such a functionality to Microsoft Teams Graph API?

The situation is even worse than it seems on the first look, because even if I enumerate ALL the teams and ALL the channels, I cannot say which ones have been modified since last time I enumerated them, because they don't have anything like "last modified time", "version" etc. For instance, if I rename a channel (or edit its description), I won't be able to figure that out during subsequent sync.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the only Microsoft Teams entity that supports delta queries are Chat Messages in channels. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#supported-resources) for supported entities across the Graph.
To request additional entities support, please go to [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/) and upvote existing ideas or create new ones.